# configure log4j to use mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, logging, log4j, nosql

In a Java project, I want to store my log entries to a noSQL db like mongoDB. Here is my log4j configuration according to [what apache claims to be working](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#NoSQLAppender):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
  <Appenders>
    <NoSql name="databaseAppender">
      <MongoDb databaseName="testLogDB" collectionName="applicationLog" server="127.0.0.1"
               username="user" password="123456" />
    </NoSql>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and the code snippet for testing:

```
static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log4j2Example.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.error("Log4j Example.");
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Apr 20, 2015 5:56:33 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2015-04-20 17:56:33,475 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.nosql.appender.mongodb.MongoDbProvider for element MongoDb. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:766)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:706)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:698)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:698)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:358)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:359)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:420)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:207)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:160)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:492)
    at logging.Log4j2Example.<clinit>(Log4j2Example.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DB.isAuthenticated()Z
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.nosql.appender.mongodb.MongoDbProvider.createNoSqlProvider(MongoDbProvider.java:178)
    ... 19 more

2015-04-20 17:56:33,484 ERROR NoSQL provider not specified for appender [databaseAppender].
2015-04-20 17:56:33,485 ERROR Null object returned for NoSql in Appenders.
2015-04-20 17:56:33,504 ERROR Unable to locate appender databaseAppender for logger
```

I have included log4j-nosql, mongo-java-driver, and log4jcore and api to my buildpath. So, what am I missing here? Feel free to suggest alternatives too.

Comment: For those who might face this in the future, I have been using mongo-java-driver-3.0.0 and log4j-nosql-2.2 which I found to be incompatible in a couple of methods. moving backward to mongo-java-driver-2.13.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

what i can find in your log4j is port number is missing.
the sample log4j is as follow:

```
<Appenders>
    <NoSql name="databaseAppender">
        <MongoDb databaseName="DB name" collectionName="collection name"
            server="localhost:27017" username="user name" password="DB password" />
    </NoSql>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
    </Root>

</Loggers>
```

you can find my sample code of noSQL appender at https://github.com/PiyushMittl/logging-wrapper-2x2

reference:https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#NoSQLAppender

Note:above example is using log4j2.x api.